# Combining SQL records that have the same the same value in a given field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say, for example, that you have the following table

```
CourseId                             | CourseTitle | EntryMonth | EntryYear |
ebdef239-abb7-4a82-9229-1ed37496da86 | Maths FT    | January    | 2013      |
57504a66-4882-4794-a8b9-af0ead38dc70 | Maths FT    | February   | 2013      |
f06c5e58-5563-4dfd-a8fc-2ce186c2106f | Maths FT    | February   | 2014      |
0c81dfe6-0b11-4cad-a27c-970dbdb2876c | Maths FT    | February   | 2015      |
ebdef239-abb7-4a82-9229-1ed37496da86 | English PT  | January    | 2013      |
57504a66-4882-4794-a8b9-af0ead38dc70 | English PT  | January    | 2014      |
```

Is it possible to write a query that would group by CourseTitle & EntryMonth, but combine the EntryYear values into a temporary column (preferably comma delimited).  So it would look this this:

```
CourseId                             | CourseTitle | EntryMonth | NewEntryYear     |
ebdef239-abb7-4a82-9229-1ed37496da86 | Maths FT    | January    | 2013             |
57504a66-4882-4794-a8b9-af0ead38dc70 | Maths FT    | February   | 2013, 2014, 2015 |
ebdef239-abb7-4a82-9229-1ed37496da86 | English PT  | January    | 2013, 2014       |
```

Any examples would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  CourseTitle
,       EntryMonth
,       stuff((
        select  ', ' + cast(EntryYear as varchar)
        from    Table1 t2
        where   t1.CourseTitle = t2.CourseTitle
                and t1.EntryMonth = t2.EntryMonth
        for xml path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') as Years
from    Table1 t1
group by
        CourseTitle
,       EntryMonth
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38e0f/5/0)

Comment: Great answer, which worked a treat.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle 10g or above, the below will work:

```
SELECT COURSEID, COURSETITLE, ENTRYMONTH, 
LISTAGG(ENTRYYEAR, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ENTRYYEAR) AS NEWENTRYYEAR
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY COURSEID, COURSETITLE, ENTRYMONTH
```

If you are not using Oracle 10g, this query would be of little help and I am sorry for that.

Comment: The question is tagged sql-server (you can see tags near the bottom of the questions)

Comment: Yes. But I thought if any Oracle user with same problem visits this question, my answer will be helpful. So I posted my answer.

Comment: Whilst it is an SQL Server question, it is still interesting to see how this could be achieved in Oracle, so thank you for that.